# Three Congruent Incircles of a divided Equilateral triangle

Tags: geometry, polynomials

Take an equilateral triangle with sides of unit length and choose a vertex from which to draw two cevians to the opposite side.These cevians divide the equilateral triangle into three subtriangles.

If these three subtriangles all have congruent incircles, can anyone confirm that the length of these cevians is $1/4(3^{1/3}+3^{2/3})$ and the inradius of the congruent incircles is $1/2(3^{1/2}/(3+3^{1/3}+3^{2/3}))$?

Using the Paul Yiu article at http://www.math-cs.ucmo.edu/~mjms/2003.1/pyiu.pdf, I had to solve a quartic equation to get the length of the cevians h where - $3 - 18 h - 27 h^2 + 16 h^3 + 48 h^4 = 0$. Is there a simpler method of calculating the cevian length? This question was first asked in Mathoverflow.

Comment: You must be given the length of the equilateral triangle at least, or something, for e.g. the side is 1?

Comment: Corrected question to give equilateral triangle unit side length per comment @Sawarnik

Comment: In $\triangle ABC$ with cevians $AP$ and $AQ$ (with $P$ near $B$ and $Q$ near $C$), if you write $p$ for $|BP|$ (which equals $|CQ|$), then you'll get a *cubic* equation, $5 - 21 p + 24 p^2 - 16 p^3 = 0$. (So that's at least *slightly* simpler than the quartic.) The cubic has a single real root, $p=\frac{1}{4}\left( 2 + 3^{1/3} - 3^{2/3} \right)$; from this, you can calculate the cevian length and inradius, which match the values you provided.

Comment: @Blue Maybe you should that as an answer with details :)

Answer (score 1):

Label elements of equilateral $\triangle ABC$ as shown:

[image]

Using the fact that

$$\text{area of } \triangle = \frac{1}{2} \cdot \text{inradius} \cdot \text{perimeter}$$

we have

$$\frac{2|\triangle APB|}{1+x+y} = r = \frac{2|\triangle APQ|}{1-2x+2y}$$
$$\frac{x \cdot \frac{\sqrt{3}}{2}}{1+x+y} = r = \frac{(1-2x) \cdot \frac{\sqrt{3}}{2}}{1-2x+2y}$$

so that
$$x ( 1 - 2 x + 2 y ) = ( 1 - 2 x )( 1 + x + y ) \quad\to\quad y ( 4 x - 1 ) = 1 - 2 x$$

By the Law of Cosines, 
$$y^2 = 1^2 + x^2 - 2\cdot 1\cdot x\cos 60^\circ = x^2 - x + 1$$

which implies
$$( x^2 - x + 1 )( 4 x - 1 )^2 = ( 1 - 2 x )^2 \quad\to\quad x (16 x^3 - 24 x^2 + 21 x - 5 ) = 0$$

The case $x=0$ is extraneous (and evidently corresponds to the alternate problem of congruent incircles in $\triangle APQ$, $\triangle ABQ$, $\triangle ACP$), and Mathematica tells me that the sole real solution to the cubic factor is 
$$x = \frac{1}{4} (2 + s - s^2) = \frac{1}{4}(2-s)(1+s)$$
where $s := 3^{1/3}$.

Then,
$$y^2 = \frac{1}{16} (6 + 3\cdot s + s^2) = \frac{1}{16}(2 s^3 + s^4 + s^2 ) = \frac{s^2}{16}(1+s)^2 \quad\to\quad y = \frac{s}{4} ( 1 + s )$$ 
$$r = \frac{\frac{\sqrt{3}}{2}(1-2x)}{1 -2x+2y} = \frac{\frac{\sqrt{3}}{4}s(s-1)}{s^2} = \frac{(s-1)\sqrt{3}}{4s} = \frac{(s^3-1)\sqrt{3}}{4s(1+s+s^2)} = \frac{\sqrt{3}}{2s(1+s+s^2)}$$
which match the values given in the problem.

Comment: Why are triangles APB and ACQ congruent?

Comment: @Sawarnik: Symmetry.

Comment: See published sequence A243508 in OEIS with acknowledgements to @Blue. Note that the original quartic is reducible to (3h+1)(16h^3-9h-3)=0.